# Angular2 Routing to a page based on search result

Tags: angular

I want to navigate to different page if the search result is only one item (if `reportId` = 1), where user can save one click. Here is my resolver code.

```
export class SearchResultsResolver implements Resolve<Report[]> {
        constructor(private searchService: SearchService, private router: Router) {}

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
         state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Report[]> {
        let reportId = route.params['reportId'];

        return this.searchService.getReports(reportId);

        console.log('reportid', reportId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply use a combination of `flatMap`, `Observer.if` and the `router.navigate` to get that done as shown in the snippet below

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Array<Report>> {
  let reportId = route.params['reportId'];

  return this.searchService.getReports(reportId)
 .flatMap(reports => Observable.if(() => reports && reports.length > 1, 
      Observable.of(reports),
      this._router.navigate(['/otherRoute']))
  );
```